# Bash not reading env?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

The context for this is that I want to read the user's path from xmonad, where the path is modified by whatever's in their .bashrc if applicable.

Here's what I find weird: if I have xmonad execute `bash -cl "env && echo $PATH"` it returns an `env` which includes one `$PATH` which does not match that returned by echo.  (I want the former.)

What gives?

And is there a way to fix this, other than parsing the `env` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell is substituting the value of $PATH first, because of the double quotes. I'm not sure what the first set of double quotes is doing, but try one of

```
'bash -cl "env && echo $PATH"'
"bash -cl 'env && echo $PATH'"
```

Now, are you trying to extract just the path from the env output? If so, `echo` is not the tool. You'd want `env | grep ^PATH=`

Comment: I've edited the original post, my formatting was unclear: the outside quotes were just to set off the command being run.  I'm trying to get the `$PATH` (as possibly modified by `~/.bash_profile` and such), I'm just doing both `env` and `echo` to compare the outputs as a troubleshooting measure.  `env` works, but I'm interested to know why echo `echo` doesn't.

Comment: The crux of this answer still stands. The `echo $PATH` part was evaluated by your current shell and its expansion passed to the subshell. Use single quotes or do this instead: `echo "$(env && echo $PATH)"`

Comment: This was reasonably close to what worked; part of the issue was, I think, how I was spawning the process in xmonad.  But it definitely helped, so thanks all!